# Time interpolation - pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a slight problem with an accurate time interpolation.

A separate file gives me a time array looking something like this. For the sake of clarity I use the same time range for both time columns in this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_time   = pd.DataFrame({
'TIMETAG': ['13:52:41.562', '13:52:41.640', '13:52:41.749', '13:52:41.838',\
            '13:52:41.948', '13:52:42.048', '13:52:42.138',\
            '13:52:42.258', '13:52:42.398', '13:52:42.584', '13:52:42.584',\
            '13:52:42.692', '13:52:42.879', '13:52:42.957',\
            '13:52:43.066', '13:52:43.176', '13:52:43.269', '13:52:43.363',\
            '13:52:43.472', '13:52:43.597', '13:52:43.722',\
            '13:52:43.815', '13:52:43.987', '13:52:44.065', '13:52:44.190',\
            '13:52:44.299', '13:52:44.392', '13:52:44.486',\
            '13:52:44.595', '13:52:44.673', '13:52:44.798', '13:52:44.970',\
            '13:52:45.001', '13:52:45.094', '13:52:45.235']})
```

I transform it to milliseconds with the following commands:

```
timerange = pd.to_datetime(df_time['TIMETAG'])
timeit    = timerange.astype('int64')//(10**6)
```

The timetag has originally more than 500 rows, the sampling rate is close to 100 milliseconds, but I still adjust it so each time step is exactly 100 ms

```
timerange = np.arange(np.amin(timeit), np.amax(timeit), 100)
```

I need to interpolate a separate dataframe, which has already a time column, however with only 58 elements (sampling is therefore approximately 9 times lower). THIS dataframe has to be interpolated to the timeit array.

```
df   = pd.DataFrame({
'TIMETAG2' : ['13:52:41.562', '13:52:42.238', '13:52:42.558' ,\
                              '13:52:42.879', '13:52:43.176' ,\
              '13:52:43.597', '13:52:44.299', '13:52:44.595' ,\
                              '13:52:44.970', '13:52:45.235'],

 '350.0'    : [13.108239, 12.398412, 13.020835, 14.030805, 13.852628   ,\
               13.901151, 13.050930, 12.642002, 11.864150, 11.297425  ],

 '400.0'    : [22.551765, 22.186752, 22.603124, 24.662806, 24.108199   ,\
               24.057507, 23.258363, 22.721349, 21.300732, 20.733452  ],


 '450.0'    : [32.221240, 32.621537, 32.367137, 35.565543, 34.632190   ,\
               34.444403, 34.098969, 33.486451, 31.556474, 31.584678  ],

 '500.0'    : [33.460819, 34.410052, 33.755817, 36.839105, 35.827079   ,\
                                   35.691536,      35.732444,      35.349296,      33.618491,     34.132295  ],

                '550.0'    : [     32.423253,      33.517339,      32.708333,      35.677932,     34.682384   ,\
                                   34.515653,      34.753437,      34.456637,      32.790737,     33.458967  ],

                '600.0'    : [     28.563580,      29.187609,      28.715661,      31.343185,     30.541189   ,\
                                   30.366380,      30.278298,      29.895978,      28.392532,     28.646102]
                            })
```

Again, I convert the time column to milliseconds:

```
df_timetag = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMETAG2'])
df_timeit  = df_timetag.astype('int64')//(10**6)
```

Setting the timestamp as index, I try to interpolate with the following commands:

```
df['TIMETAG2'] = df_timeit
df1            = df.set_index('TIMETAG2')
df2            = df1.reindex(timerange)
```

The df2 is full of NaNs except the first row.

```
df3 = df2.interpolate(axis=0, limit_direction='both')
```

After the interpolation all the values in each column are practically equal.

The same thing happens when I use the time arrays of lengths 530 vs 60 (from the dataframe). This is a simpler example.

My question is: how can one successfully interpolate timewise when the time range is the same, but one array has much more elements than the other?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the reindexing line - check the correction if you need it. Now it works

```
df2 = df1.reindex(index=df1.index.union(timerange))
df3 = df2.interpolate(axis=0, limit_direction='both')
```

In case you need only the indices with values from the timerange array:

```
df4 = df3.loc[timerange]
```